# PageController jumpToPage invokes weird carousel behaviour

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, widget

I am currently utilizing the expandable_page_view library to achieve greater flexibility in the height of carousel items. Here's my widget:

```
ExpandablePageView.builder(
                  controller: _pageController,
                  onPageChanged: _onShopItemScrolled,
                  itemCount: _currentShops.length,
                  itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                    final shopItem = ShopItem(
                      shop: _currentShops[index],
                      origin: _mapController.camera.center,
                    );

                    return SlideTransition(
                      position: _slidingAnimation,
                      child: shopItem,
                    );
                  }),
                ),
```

https://vimeo.com/manage/videos/893804422

In the provided video, you'll notice that each time I tap on a marker, the jumpToPage() method is called. However, this action seems to have an unexpected impact on the widget being constructed. I didn't encounter these issues when I was using the carousel_slider package. However, I switched to expandable_page_view because I require the flexibility in height, which the former package lacks.

This is the shortened method that is being invoked through the marker.

```
  void _updateSelectedShopMarker(Map<String, dynamic> shop) async {
    setState(() {
      _previousShopId = shop["id"];
      _currentShopIndex = _currentShops.indexOf(shop);
      if (_currentShopIndex == -1) {
        return;
      }
      if (!_onMarkerShowSelectedShop) {
        _onMarkerShowSelectedShop = true;
      } else {
        if (_pageController != null) {
          _pageController!.jumpToPage(_currentShopIndex);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

I have already ruled out the animation as the source of the problem. I tested the entire carousel without the SliderTransition, and the issue persisted. Any insights into resolving this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following answer is based on assumption that problem is jumping animation behaviour.

## Firstly some explanation, why this happens.

Internally this plugin (expandable_page_view) animates the widget from the previous size to the size of new page. It maintains a list of sizes, which is pre-filled with the value of constructor parameter `estimatedPageSize` (default value is 0).

The build method that animates the page:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TweenAnimationBuilder<double>(
      curve: widget.animationCurve,
      duration: _getDuration(),
      tween: Tween<double>(begin: _previousSize, end: _currentSize),
      builder: (context, value, child) => SizedBox(
        height: _isHorizontalScroll ? value : null,
        width: !_isHorizontalScroll ? value : null,
        child: child,
      ),
      child: _buildPageView(),
    );
  }
```

This build method is called every time PageController notifies listeners about page change (`_updatePage` calls `setState` method):

```
_pageController.addListener(_updatePage);
```

```
void _updatePage() {
    final newPage = _pageController.page!.round();
    if (_currentPage != newPage) {
      setState(() {
        _firstPageLoaded = true;
        _previousPage = _currentPage;
        _currentPage = newPage;
      });
    }
  }
```

So basically, when the page is changed instantly (without animation, by calling `jumpToPage`), then build method called too early, when the size of new page is still unknown, so for some time page is animated from previous size to 0. But shortly after, page performs layout and notifies about its size, which triggers next rebuild and animation, but this time to the size of the page. And this may look like laggy / jumping animation.

Widget that triggers build method and animation when layout is already performed and size is known:

```
  Widget _itemBuilder(BuildContext context, int index) {
    final item = widget.itemBuilder!(context, index);
    return OverflowPage(
      onSizeChange: (size) => setState(
        () => _sizes[index] = _isHorizontalScroll ? size.height : size.width,
      ),
      child: item,
      alignment: widget.alignment,
      scrollDirection: widget.scrollDirection,
    );
  }
```

## Possible solutions:

1. Solution can be to just remove `setState` from `_updatePage` method. But this requires internal changes to plugin code and further testing.

```
  void _updatePage() {
    final newPage = _pageController.page!.round();
    if (_currentPage != newPage) {
      _firstPageLoaded = true;
      _previousPage = _currentPage;
      _currentPage = newPage;
    }
  }
```

Also `setState` should be removed from `_updateSelectedShopMarker` method (probably state management solution should be used, that allows to rebuild only specific widgets (flutter_bloc for example), so `ExpandablePageView.builder` will not be rebuilt too early, when new page is selected):

```
  void _updateSelectedShopMarker(Map<String, dynamic> shop) async {
    _previousShopId = shop['id'];
    _currentShopIndex = currentShops.indexOf(shop);
    if (_currentShopIndex == -1) {
      return;
    }
    if (!_onMarkerShowSelectedShop) {
      _onMarkerShowSelectedShop = true;
    } else {
      if (_pageController != null) {
        _pageController!.jumpToPage(_currentShopIndex);
      }
    }
  }
```

This way `build` method and animation will be triggered when widget has already performed layout, so size is known. (See `_itemBuilder` method above)

2. A workaround could be to set `ExpandablePageView.builder` animation duration to 0, though then page will blink (reappear) after page change:

```
 ExpandablePageView.builder(
               animationDuration: Duration.zero,
   ...
```

3. Another option is to use something else, i.e. just widget with animation instead of `ExpandablePageView.builder` if that would meet your requirements.

```
AnimatedSize(
               duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
               child: AnimatedSwitcher(
                 duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                 child: ShopItem(
                   shop: _currentShops[index],
                   origin: _mapController.camera.center,
                 ),
               ),
             )
```

Of course there could be other solutions, such as using other widget depending on requirements or creating custom widget.